# Some confusion regarding AngularJS architecture

Tags: angularjs

Recently I bought a fuse AngularJS theme from http://themeforest.net/item/fuse-angularjs-material-design-admin-template/12931855 but what kind of AngularJS architecture does this code follow? All Files Are Separate modules, controller and HTML file, and it uses gulp to run

This is Module

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.components.tables.datatable', [])
    .config(config);

/** @ngInject */
function config($stateProvider)
{
    $stateProvider.state('app.components_tables_datatable', {
        url    : '/components/table/datatable',
        views  : {
            'content@app': {
                templateUrl: 'app/main/components/tables/datatable/datatable.html',
                controller : 'DatatableController as vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            Employees: function (apiResolver)
            {
                return apiResolver.resolve('tables.employees100@get');
            }
        }
    });
}

})();
```

This is Controller

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.components.tables.datatable')
    .controller('DatatableController', DatatableController);

/** @ngInject */
function DatatableController(Employees)
{
    var vm = this;

    // Data
    vm.employees = Employees.data;

    vm.dtOptions = {
        dom       : '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"<"left"<"length"l>><"right"<"info"i><"pagination"p>>>',
        pagingType: 'simple',
        autoWidth : false,
        responsive: true
    };

    // Methods

    //////////
}

})();
```

[image: Folder Structure Screenshots]

Comment: See this popular style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good [documentation](http://withinpixels.com/themes/fuse/documentation/getting-started/introduction) which helps to start with Fuse theme's angular version.
http://withinpixels.com/themes/fuse/documentation/getting-started/introduction

It uses modular structure under /app directory. To add a new module, simply put your module files into your preferred location inside the app/ directory and then add the module name as a dependency into the app/index.module.js file.

Unzip the zip file that you have downloaded from Themeforest. Inside the zip file, you will find the Skeleton Project (Fuse-1.x.x.zip) along with the Demo Project (Fuse-1.x.x-demo.zip), PSD designs and a readme file. After extracting Fuse-1.x.x.zip or Fuse-1.x.x-demo.zip, you will find /src folder where you need to build your modules under /app folder. After completing you need to run "gulp build" (for production) or "gulp build:dev" (for development). Finally you will get your build theme under /dist folder. Now you can use it in any where. Even you can run using apache server.